# Getting build errors on server side components with NextJS 13 appdir functionality

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

I'm looking to host my nextjs13 site on Vercel but I'm experiencing some errors. I'm using the appdirectory functionality which I believe is still in beta, and I'm also using Typescript which I think could also cause some issues with Next.

The site works fine on my local machine, including all fetch requests, but these are crashing when the CLI is trying to generate the static pages.
This is one of the errors I'm getting (I'm getting 4 of the same, one for each of the server components I'm using):

```
(node:457) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async fetchPageInfo (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:664:20)
    at async About (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:679:18) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3000
  }
```

Here is my page.tsx:

```
import {
  Experience,
  PageInfo,
  Project,
  Skill,
  Social,
} from "@/pages/api/typings";

import About from "./Components/about";
import Contact from "./Components/contact";
import WorkExperience from "./Components/experience";
import Header from "./Components/header";
import Hero from "./Components/hero";
import Projects from "./Components/projects";
import Skills from "./Components/skills";

type Props = {
  pageInfo: PageInfo;
  experiences: Experience;
  skills: Skill[];
  projects: Project[];
  socials: Social[];
};

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="h-screen snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-scroll bg-background z-0 scrollbar scrollbar-track-textColour scrollbar-thumb-menuColour">
      <Header />
      <section className="snap-center">
        <Hero />
      </section>
      <section className="snap-center" id="about">
        {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
        <About />
      </section>
      <section className="snap-center" id="experience">
        {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
        <WorkExperience />
      </section>
      <section className="snap-center" id="skills">
        {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
        <Skills />
      </section>
      <section className="snap-start" id="projects">
        {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
        <Projects />
      </section>
      <section className="snap-start" id="contact">
        <Contact />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

About, WorkExperience, Skills, and Projects are all server components, the others are using state so are client.

I'm happy to share any other code snippets that may help.

I've tried to made sure all the directories are where they should be, all .env are declared and working. I've tried running the build using the CLI from VScode, as well as using the github repo from the web ui. Struggling to think of what I can do next.

Comment: Are you fetching data in the page.tsx or in the other comnponents?